# PHP replace specific words with other wpecific words in string

Tags: php, arrays, replace, str-replace

Here is the scenario: I need to replace specific words with some other specific words, but I have a really long list of words to replace, about 200

So far I used an array which contains the words to be replaced. And in another array , the new words. I wanted to know if there's another way, shorter and nicer, to do this ?

here is what my code looks like (only 4 words in this example)

```
<?php
$newTitle = ucfirst(strtolower($title)) // random title, different each time;

$lookFor = array(" word one " , " word two " , " word 3 " , " word 4 ");

$replaceWith  = array(
" NEW word one ",
" NEW word 2 ",
" NEW word 3 ",
" NEW word four "
// etc... about 200 words
);
?>

<h2>
    <?php echo str_replace($lookFor, $replaceWith, $newTitle);?>
</h2>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Are those real examples as in are you just adding "NEW "?  Or it could be replace cat with dog?

Comment: @Amal Murali: I'm not saying this approach doesn't work, I just wanted to know if there is a better approach to replace some specific words.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : yea " NEW word one " would replace " word one " in this example. I'm just curious if there is another better way than putting all words into arrays to make those replacement.

Comment: This is how I would do it, but my point was if all you are doing is adding the same word "NEW" then it is much easier.

Comment: Ok thanks for your info. Oh no, "NEW" is just repeated here for the example. They all are different words. I will stick with this approach. Thanks.